# Composition of Functions Properties

Tags: real-analysis

Say I have functions $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ and $g:[c,d]\to [a,b]$. Are the proofs trivial for: if $f$ and $g$ are continuous, then $f(g(x))$ is continuous on $[c,d]$ and similarly replacing continuous with monotonic?

Comment: For monotonic, the proof is very easy (maybe trivial), for continuous, it is harder but not too bad.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the topological definition for continuity it is even easier. A function is continuous if the pre-image of any open set is open. So let $f\circ g$ be a composition of two continuous functions with $g:X\rightarrow Y$ and $f:Y\rightarrow Z$.

To prove that the composition of is continuous take an open set $A$ in $Z$, the preimage under $f\circ g$ is just $g^{-1}(f^{-1}A))$ but $f^{-1}(A)$ is an open set in $Y$ since $f$ is continuous and $A$ is open in $Z$. Because of this $g^{-1}(f^{-1}(A))$ is open since $g$ is continuous and $f^{-1}(A)$ is an open set of $Y$.Since the preimage of any open set is open the composition is continuous.

---

Proving a composition of monotonic functions is monotonic is easier. You just have to consider the four cases: ($f$ can be increasing-decreasing  and so can $g$).

I will do the case where $f$ is increasing and $g$ is decreasing and prove $f\circ g$ is monotonic (decreasing).

Let $x_1>x_2$, We shall prove $f(g(x_1))\leq f(g(x_2))$. Since $g$ is decreasing $g(x_1)\leq g(x_2)$ because of this when we apply $f$ to $g(x_2)$ it is greater than when we apply $f$ to $g(x_1)$ (Because $f$ is increasing). So we get $f(g(x_2)\geq f(g(x_1))$ as desired.

Comment: I understand the monotonic argument. However, I am not familiar with pre-images. Is there another way to prove f ∘ g is continuous?

Answer (score 0):

To prove $f \circ g$ continuous at $a$ we must show that for every $\epsilon > 0$, there's a $\delta > 0$ such that $|x - a| < \delta$ implies $|f(g(x)) - f(g(a))| < \epsilon.$ (That's the def'n of continuity).

Suppose we're given $\epsilon$. I'll show how to find $\delta$. Let's call $g(a)$ by the name $b$. Since $f$ is continuous, it's continuous at $b$. So starting with our $\epsilon$, there's some number $\gamma > 0$ such that $|y - b| < \gamma$ implies $f(y) - f(b) < \epsilon$. (That's just the defn of continuity, with a few symbols renamed).

Now since $\gamma$'s a number greater than zero, we can use it as the "epsilon" in the definition of continuity for $g$ at $a$. We find that there must be some number $\delta$ with the property that $|x - a| < \delta$ implies $|g(x) - g(a) | < \gamma$. I'll rewrite that slightly:

$|x - a| <\delta$ implies $|g(x) - b| < \gamma$.

Now for ANY number $y$, we have that $|y - b| < \gamma$ implies $|f(y) - f(b)| < \epsilon$. Apply this to the number $y = g(x)$ to get that

$|g(x) - b| < \gamma$ implies $|f(g(x)) - f(b)| < \epsilon$.

But we know that $|x - a| < \delta$ ensures that $|g(x) - b| < \gamma$, so we can say that

$|x - a| < \delta$ implies $|f(g(x)) - f(b)| < \epsilon$.

Finally, remembering that $b$ is just $g(a)$, we can rewrite this as

$|x - a| < \delta$ implies $|f(g(x)) - f(g(a))| < \epsilon$.

And that shows that $f \circ g$ is continuous at $a$. Since $a$ was arbitrary, it shows that $f \circ g$ is continuous everywhere.